# How to drill to insert rebar into a large rock (5mx5mx5m)

Tags: concrete, drill, rebar

I am pouring a reinforced concrete beam. It contains rebar. I would like to insert the rebar (horizontally) into this rock:

[image: rock]

What kind of drill and drill bit and to what depth should I drill to insert the rebar? My beam is using 10* 16mm steel bars, although I could use a lower size for the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

A [rotary hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_drill#Rotary_hammers) is the standard tool for a job like this, with a carbide-tipped masonry bit. You can rent a heavy-duty model at your local rental center. They're not difficult to use. Be sure to wear ear, eye, and resipration protection.

As for your question about depth, you haven't provided nearly enough information about your plans for anyone to speculate.

Comment: is there any way to determine the appropriate strength of the drill?

I  am in Indonesia, and there are SDS-plus hammers of 1.7 up to 5 joule, and SDS-max with 8.5 up to 15 joule.